# Most used Free (a in Open) Joomla Extensions

Tags: joomla

I've just come back to using Joomla, and the number of extensions that claim to be Open Source, but then offer a 'free' and crippled version to tempt users to the paid proper version is a little gutting.

What are the trully Open extensions most in use, and for what ? (One extension per answer)

Comment: Shame this was closed - it's a very good point (i.e. a big flaw of joomla), and I'd be interested in the answers! Please drop by and support the [Joomla StackExchange proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34294/joomla-answers) where you'll be able to ask this very type of question.